# "pull on a rope" or "pull with a rope"?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition do I have to use in the following sentence?

> My car got stuck and we pulled it out **on**/**with** a rope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are grammatical, but idiomatically I would use the preposition 'with':

> My car got stuck and we pulled it out **with** a rope.

The preposition 'on' would be used in a different sentence

> We pulled **on** the rope which was tied to the car.

Comment: What is the difference between "pull the rope" and pull on the rope"?

Comment: Very little, but "pull on" seems more purposeful. You can "pull a rope" without the intention of moving the car, for example to test if the knot is tight. I wanted a sentence which uses "on" as in the question.